# How to change <DatePicker /> selected year's background color with sx prop in MUI X?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I'm struggling to change selected year or month's background color on  component in MUI X. It's not clear on documentation. Year Picker shows up when I click on month and year.

I was able to change background color for selected day, but not for year. In devtools it shows .MuiPickersYear-yearButton.Mui-selected classnames but when i use them nothing changes.

```
slotProps={{
            day: {
              sx: {
                '&.MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected': {
                  backgroundColor: '#f0ca4d',
                },
              },
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to a space between the `&` operator and the class selector `.`, so:

```
slotProps={{
            day: {
              sx: {
                '& .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected': {
                  backgroundColor: '#f0ca4d',
                },
                '& .MuiPickersYear-yearButton.Mui-selected':{
                  backgroundColor: '#f0ca4d',
                }
              },
            },
```

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work. The default color is still different on selected year, it becomes my color only when I click somewhere else. Adding hover and focus also didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: The only thing I can think of then is to use the MUI theme element and change it there, example - https://github.com/mui/material-ui-pickers/issues/393

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the year selector to the `desktopPaper` slot prop rather than the `day` slot prop. This worked for me:

```js
slotProps={{
  tabs: {
    hidden: false,
  },
  inputAdornment: {
    position: 'start'
  },
  day: {
    sx: {
      '&.MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor: '#0079FF',
      },
    }
  },
  desktopPaper: {
    sx: {
      '.MuiPickersYear-yearButton.Mui-selected':{
        backgroundColor: '#0079FF',
      }
    }
  },
}}
```

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155508/im-using-mui-x-date-pickers-6-10-0-i-would-like-to-know-how-to-change-the-col).